# Catch error in Dialog - IBM Watson Conversation

Tags: node.js, json, ibm-watson

Is there anyway to read the following error from IBM log and use it as a condition in my dialog.

```
> "  "error": "Error when updating context with context of dialog node
> id [node_9_1585679414490]. Dialog Node context is
> [{\"errCFM\":0,\"errCRM\":0,\"errPhone\":0,\"contador1\":0,\"inputteste\":\"<?output.nodes_visited_details[0].next_step.selector?>\",\"contadorCRM\":1,\"retentarCFM\":1,\"errControlUF\":0,\"contadorGeral\":1,\"errControlCard\":0,\"errControlExames\":0,\"contadorValidaCFM\":1,\"contadorNomeMedico\":1,\"contadorGeralCartao\":1,\"contadorValidaCartao\":1,\"contadorValidarExame\":1,\"contadorCFMEncontrado\":1,\"contadorCRMEncontrado\":1,\"contadorIntegracaoCFM\":1,\"contadorCFMNaoEncontrado\":1,\"contadorIntegracaoCartao\":1,\"contadorIntegracaoUnibem\":1,\"contadorQuantidadeCodigo\":1,\"contadorQuantidadeValida\":1,\"contadorQuantidadeInvalida\":1,\"contadorIntegracaoPagerDuty\":1,\"contadorIntegracaoProtocolo\":1,\"contadorIntegracaoRegistrarOS\":1,\"contadorIntegracaoSalvarBanco\":1,\"contadorIntegracaoValidarCodigo\":1}].\nSpEL
> evaluation error: Expression
> [output.nodes_visited_details[0].next_step.selector] at position 28:
> EL1012E: Cannot index into a null value\n","
```

Comment: What code have you written for this so far? What errors you are encountering?

Comment: So far I was just trying to access from IBM Watson conversation, I'm just starting to work with IBM Watson conversation. My thoughts was that if I am able to use de user input with "input.text", I maybe be able to use the output with something like "output.error".

Comment: IBM watson provide an API to read logs of last 30 days, check that API